# JQuery / PHP dynamically connect to network sql server database

Tags: php, jquery, html5builder

I'm totally new to this and to be honest I'm struggling to even find any basic documentation/tutorials on the subject.

I'm using Embacadero HTML5 Builder to try and create an iphone basic app

I have a basic form with 2 edit boxes and a button.
All I'm trying to do is when the user clicks the button, it takes the username and password from the edits and trys to connect to a sql server (2012).

I know the IP address of the server and the database name.

If the connection fails due to incorrect logon, then a warning message is displayed.
If the connection works, then it should open up the "next" page, whatever that is.

All I have so far, which I know doesn't work is below, but you get the general gist.

```
function btnLoginClick($sender, $params)
{
    $mysqlsvr = new SQLConnection('10.10.1.27', $edUsername.Text, $edPassword.Text, 'exp_main');
    $mysqlsvr.open;

    if fails then
        WARNING
    else
        Open new page
}
```

I'd like to pass this database connection through if connects fine, or just store it somewhere globally for use.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Accessing the user input

You are using the wrong identifiers to access the *username* and *password* entered by the user.

```
$text = $this->ComponentName->Text; // Right.
$text = $ComponentName.Text; // Wrong.
```

## Connecting to an MSSQL server

To configure an MSSQL connection with HTML5 Builder, follow these pages of the documentation:

- **[Server Database Connections](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/HTML5_Builder/en/Server_Database_Connections)** (*general information to configure a connection*)
- **[Microsoft SQL Server](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/HTML5_Builder/en/Microsoft_SQL_Server)**

HTML5 Buider also includes a tool, the **[Data Explorer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/HTML5_Builder/en/Data_Explorer)**, which you can use to connect the IDE itself to your server, so you can *drag and drop* tables into the Designer to generate the components for the connection, instead of creating and configuring those manually.

## PHP

Finally, I see you are using Delphi-like code for your event handler. HTML5 Builder is an Embarcadero product, yes, but it uses web programming languages such as JavaScript or PHP. For server-side event handlers, you must use the latter.

While you do not need a high level of PHP for using HTML5 Builder, you should learn the basics. The H5B documentation includes some pages with references to PHP [documentation resources](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/HTML5_Builder/en/Documentation#PHP) and [tutorials](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/HTML5_Builder/en/Tutorials#PHP). I would start with the **[W3Schools Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)**, which will give you the basics, and you will find out the **[official PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/)**, while a bit messy in some aspects, is really helpful and convers almost everything you might ever need.

Comment: Hi Gallaecio,

That's great thanks, total new way of coding for me so somewhere I can check out the basics is good.

Comment: I forgot to say Gallaecio.
I know I can set the properties in the designer to connect to the database, but I want to set the username and password on the object from the edit boxes on the form, then set the connected property of the object to true. I can't connect to the db on startup as I don't know who the user will be.
If I wrote it in delphi it would look something like this.

Comment: function btnLoginClick($sender, $params)
    {                     
        dmMain.Username := edUsername.Text;
        dmMain.UserPassword := edPassword.Text;
        try
          dmMain.Connected := True; 
          LoadNextPage;
        except
          ShowMessage('You dont have access')
        end;          
    }

Comment: Hmmm that didn't format like before but hopefully you can read it and understand what I am getting at.

Comment: Ok I understand how to pass the information through to my object

        $this->dmMain->UserName = $this->edUsername->Text;
        $this->dmMain->UserPassword = $this->edPassword->Text;
        $this->dmMain->Connected = True;

Now need to find out about handling a successful or not connection.

Thanks for your help

Comment: @Gallaecio I still have H5B in use, but now I had to upgrade to PHP 5.6+ and the mysql db connection does not work anymore. Have you an idear what I have to change? Is it not compatible anymore with PHP 5.6+ ( I know that mysql changed to mysqli / PDO in PHP. Any help what to do?) Thanks